# How to use Promise and setTimeout within a generator function in order to create an async generator?

Tags: javascript, function, async-await, promise, generator

I'm trying to write a generator function which creates an async generator. The Generator should yield a deferred value at time, each via a promise. The value and the related delay (in milliseconds) come from two different arrays.

As for the provided example code the expected behavior is a logging sequence where, one after the other and waiting for one another, each `value` from the `target` array gets logged with its related (same index) `delay` from the `timeArray` until the end of the `target` array's iteration.

I tried using the code shown below but it only prints out the first 2 elements in the `timeArray` but it doesn't print all of the other elements and I'm not sure if it's printing them after the first two time intervals in `timeArray`

```
let j = 0;

// Array that shows how long after each number printed
// to the console the next value should be printed.
var timeArray = [6, 68, 51, 41, 94, 65, 47, 85, 76, 136];

// Array of numbers that should be printed.
var targets = [9, 10, 8, 7, 9, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7];

let generator = generateSequence();

async function* generateSequence(casiInfluence) {
  yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log(targetArray[j]), timeArray[j]); console.log(timeArray[j]);
  });
}
(async function main() {
  for await (var result of generateSequence()) {
    console.log(result);
    j++;
    result = generator.next();
  }
}());
```

Comment: Your code is missing something and can't be run

Comment: Do you have to use a generator? It's not necessary to print the numbers with delays.

Comment: @ChrisYoung ... From all the provided answers / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

For each step towards a generator for deferred values the OP could implement an own task ... like ...

- mapping both of the OP's arrays into a better processable data-structure ... here an array of tuples where each tuple is made of ... `[<value>, <delay>]`.
- mapping of each value-delay tuple into a deferred value action which is an async function that creates and returns a promise which will resolve the `value` after the milliseconds `delay` where the mapping function that creates the async function is called `createDeferredValue`.
- creating the async generator from the array of async functions where the generator function is called `createPoolOfDeferredValues`.

```js
// - a specific helper which creates an async function
//   (encapsulating a promise) for each to be deferred value.
function createDeferredValue(value, delay) {
  return async function () {
    return await (
      new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, value))
    );
  };
}

// - another helper which creates an async generator
//   from an array of async functions.
async function* createPoolOfDeferredValues(deferredValueList) {
  const asyncFunctions = [...deferredValueList];

  let asyncFct;
  while (asyncFct = asyncFunctions.shift()) {

    yield (await asyncFct());
  }
}


// - array that defines how long after each to be
//   processed value the next value will be processed.
const valueDelays = [600, 680, 510, 410, 940, 650, 470, 850, 760, 1360];

// - array of to be processed target values.
const targetValues = [9, 10, 8, 7, 9, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7]


// - maps both above OP's arrays into a
//   better processable data-structure.
const targetEntries = targetValues
  .map((value, idx) => [value, valueDelays[idx]]);

console.log({ targetEntries });

// - helper task which creates a list of async functions.
const deferredValueList = targetEntries
  .map(([value, delay]) =>
    createDeferredValue(value, delay)
  );

// create an async generator ...
const poolOfDeferredValues =
  createPoolOfDeferredValues(deferredValueList);

(async () => {
  // ... and iterate over it.
  for await (const value of poolOfDeferredValues) {
    console.log({ value });
  }
})();

console.log('... running ...');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

But of cause, once having created the list/array of async functions,
one can iterate it directly with `for...await` without the detour of an async generator. Thus the above provided code simplifies to ...

```js
// - a specific helper which creates an async function
//   (encapsulating a promise) for each to be deferred value.
function createDeferredValue(value, delay) {
  return async function () {
    return await (
      new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, value))
    );
  };
}

// - array that defines how long after each to be
//   processed value the next value will be processed.
const valueDelays = [600, 680, 510, 410, 940, 650, 470, 850, 760, 1360];

// - array of to be processed target values.
const targetValues = [9, 10, 8, 7, 9, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7]


// - maps both above OP's arrays into a
//   better processable data-structure.
const targetEntries = targetValues
  .map((value, idx) => [value, valueDelays[idx]]);

console.log({ targetEntries });

// - helper task which creates a list of async functions.
const deferredValueList = targetEntries
  .map(([value, delay]) =>
    createDeferredValue(value, delay)
  );

(async () => {
  // - iterate the list of async functions by `for...await`.
  for await (const deferredValue of deferredValueList) {
    const value = await deferredValue();
    console.log({ value });
  }
})();

console.log('... running ...');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You created the generator with `let generator = generateSequence()`, but then you never iterated over it.

(This is spread out and uses more variable names, so it's easier to read):

```
var timeArray = [6, 68, 51, 41, 94, 65, 47, 85, 76, 136];//Array that shows how long after each number printed to the console the next value should be printed
var targets = [9, 10, 8, 7, 9, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7];//Array of numbers that should be printed

var generator = generateSequence();

( async () => {

    for await ( const printNumber of generator ) {
        /* Accessing the generator's properties logs to the console, so... 
           Nothing to do in this for{} loop. */
    }

} )()

async function* generateSequence() {
    for ( const i in timeArray ) {
        const delay = timeArray[ i ];
        const numberToPrint = targets[ i ];
        await waitForPrint( numberToPrint, delay );
        yield;
    }
}

function waitForPrint( text, delay ) {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(
            () => {
                console.log( text );
                resolve();
            },
            delay
        )
    })
}
```

This would be easier without generators:

```
var timeArray = [6, 68, 51, 41, 94, 65, 47, 85, 76, 136];//Array that shows how long after each number printed to the console the next value should be printed
var targets = [9, 10, 8, 7, 9, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7];//Array of numbers that should be printed


for( let scheduledTimeMS=0, i=0; i<timeArray.length; i++ ) {

    const numberToPrint = targets[ i ];
    const delay = timeArray[ i ];

    scheduledTimeMS += delay;

    setTimeout( () => console.log( numberToPrint ), scheduledTimeMS );

}
```